# Error with Finding symbol for my type of scanner etc

Tags: java

I'm doing a tax calculator which involves multiple variables i stumble upon a brick wall on the coding which is

I tried putting a different variable but still the same error

```
    System.out.print("Single[1] o Married[2]");
    s= input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Dependents (max[4])");
    e =input.nextInt();
```

error find symbol 
error came up with s = input.nextInt;

symbol:nextInt
location: type of scanner

Comment: Have you declared your own `Scanner` class?

Answer (score 0):

The input object you have has to be first created from the Scanner class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Single[1] o Married[2]");
int s = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Dependents (max[4])");
int e =input.nextInt();
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Is **input** variable is instance/object of **java.util.Scanner** class? If not then please create object of **Scanner** class and use it as follow

```
import java.util.Scanner;

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Single[1] o Married[2]");
int s = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Dependents (max[4])");
int e =input.nextInt();
```